# SQL select where two different names are within a certain time of each other

Tags: sql

Hi I need to return values only where both names are found within a certain time frame

```
Primary Start_Time            NAME
A12345  22:00:00  FIRST
A12345 22:05:00  SECOND
A12345 21:00:00  FIRST
A12345 21:10:00  SECOND
A54321 21:00:00 FIRST
A54321 21:01:00 SECOND
```

In this instance if we said they need to return the values where FIRST and SECOND have occurred within 5 minutes of each other and they both have the same Primary ID

```
SELECT    Table1.Primary,  Table1.START_TIME,  Table2.NAME
FROM            Table1 INNER JOIN
                        Table2 ON Table1.Table2_KEY = Table2.LINK
Where (Table2.NAME = 'First') or (Table2.NAME = 'Second')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I have added the query in now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the SQL LAG function. The following example generalizes your question so that it will be clear and more useful to a broader audience.

Assume that your joined result set is named "t." The following example gives you what you'd need to get to your answer...

```
select 
    *
    ,lag([Start_Time],1) over (partition by [Primary] order by [Primary],[Start_Time]) as PriorTime
    ,lag([Name],1) over (partition by [Primary] order by [Primary],[Start_Time]) as PriorName
from t
```

This returns:
[image]

Hopefully, you can take it from there... namely, filtering for rows for which the time difference is acceptably small, but here is one example of the next step...

```
 select 
     *
    ,case when PriorName = 'FIRST' and [Name] = 'SECOND' then datediff(s,[Start_Time],[PriorTime]) else null end as TimeDiff
from
(
    select 
        *
        ,lag([Start_Time],1) over (partition by [Primary] order by [Primary],[Start_Time]) as PriorTime
        ,lag([Name],1) over (partition by [Primary] order by [Primary],[Start_Time]) as PriorName
    from t
) src
```

...which gives you...
[image]

Comment: This is close to doing it for me in an understandable way but this is not using the NAME field to check if the priortime NAME is not equal to the start_time name

Comment: Ah... is there the potential for FIRST, FIRST, SECOND, SECOND? If not, then, as written, you would be good.

Comment: Yes there could be nothing but FIRST's or nothing but SECOND's so I only want it to ultimately return values which have first and second within a certain time

Comment: Ok - aside from the fact that raises some interesting questions about the underlying data, you would go with my original recommendation but include logic in your "certain time" test that considers whether or not the prior row was a "FIRST" and current row is a "SECOND." I have edited the recommendation to cover that.

Comment: This looks very workable for me now as I can get down to manageable sized recordset. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can use `exists`.  `date/time` function vary significantly among databass, but the idea is:

```
select t.*
from t
where (name = 'FIRST' and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.primary = t.primary and t2.name = 'SECOND' and
                     t2.start_time between t.start_time - interval '5 minute' and t.start_time + interval '5 minute'
              )
      ) or
      (name = 'SECOND' and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.primary = t.primary and t2.name = 'FIRST' and
                     t2.start_time between t.start_time - interval '5 minute' and t.start_time + interval '5 minute'
              )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports OLAP functions, this could be what you need: ...

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(prim,start_time,nam) AS (
          SELECT 'A12345',TIME '22:00:00','FIRST'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A12345',TIME '22:05:00','SECOND'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A12345',TIME '21:00:00','FIRST'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A12345',TIME '21:10:00','SECOND'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A54321',TIME '21:00:00','FIRST'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A54321',TIME '21:01:00','SECOND'
)
,
-- create an in-line table with the next following values ...
with_next AS (
  SELECT
    prim
  , start_time
  , LEAD(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY prim ORDER BY start_time) AS end_time
  , LEAD(start_time) OVER(PARTITION BY prim ORDER BY start_time) 
    - start_time AS the_interval
  , nam
  , LEAD(nam       ) OVER(PARTITION BY prim ORDER BY start_time) AS end_nam
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  *
FROM with_next
WHERE the_interval <= INTERVAL '5 minutes';
-- out   prim  | start_time | end_time | the_interval |  nam  | end_nam 
-- out --------+------------+----------+--------------+-------+---------
-- out  A12345 | 22:00:00   | 22:05:00 | 00:05        | FIRST | SECOND
-- out  A54321 | 21:00:00   | 21:01:00 | 00:01        | FIRST | SECOND
```

Comment: This is so close, however it's not liking the Line 23
Incorrect syntax near '5 MIN'.

Comment: Then try two different formats for the interval literal: a) `'5 MINUTES'` and b) `'00:05:00'`